# Android: Problem getting File frm URI generated by FIleProvider

Tags: java, android, file, uri, android-fileprovider

I create a file in external storage like this
my filename is `(UP)VwJp5A9ASZFTmcIxVf+Yqg==.jpg`

```java
public static File createFileInExternalStorage(Context context, String filename, byte[] content) throws IOException{
        // this is my external file dir path
        //  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{my package}/files
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(content);
        fos.close();
        return file;
    }
```

Then I turn it into a URI using file provider

```java
File file = createFileInExternalStorage(context, filename, data);
String authority = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider";
Uri processedUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, file);
```

But I have problem turning this URI back to the original file

```java
String path = uri.getPath();
// path is ->   /name2/(UP)VwJp5A9ASZFTmcIxVf+Yqg==.jpg
 File fdelete = new File(path); 
 !fdelete.exists()  // false
```

My `provider_paths.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="name1" path="."/>
    <external-files-path name="name2" path="." />
</paths>
```

the name2 from `uri.getPath()` definitely come from the name in `external-files-path`
can someone explain what this name is? It create a folder call myimages in the internal storage? What if I just want the file to be save directly inside internal storage folder (top level)? It force me to create a sub folder?

[image]

taken from https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing

Comment: Have a look at uri.toString() .

Comment: `I have problem turning this URI back to the original file` Why would you wanna do so?

Comment: I downloaded an encrypted file from server, and created a local copy, after I decrypt the file and created a decrypted version of the file, I might or might not need the original encrypted version of the file. If I don't need it, I should delete it